# InDesign link options not working

Tags: adobe-indesign

I have multiple text file linked to InDesign document. Now when I am updating outside files, entire formatting inside InDesign is vanishing. I am unable to keep formatting while updating in external files. I have tried setting link options (see below), but no luck. I am still loosing formatting after update. Any idea what is happening ? Only other options seems like having formatted excel cell and import it. However is there way to achieve this with ".txt" files?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, this is a normal (and quite frustrating) behavior. I suggest you try Adobe's InCopy, which should solve your problem. A trial is available.

Comment: InCopy is part of the CC Suite, so if the OP is a subscriber they should be able to give it a try.